# Excel VBA Search for Value in Column A Select Row Value is Found and Column F as Active Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA newbie...

I am looking for value "A" in column A. I would then like to use the row number which value "A" is located at, and copy the existing function in Column F into Column E.

This is what I tried and which clearly does not work...

```
Dim A_Row As Long
A_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("A", Range("A:A"), 0)
Range("E" & A_Row).Select
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if you are going to use vba then avoid using worksheet functions unless totally necessary.

```
Sub caroll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim A_row As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Loop through column A
    For Each rng In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        'Test whether cell = "A","B", or "Z"
        If VarType(rng) <> vbError Then
            If rng.Value = "A" Or rng.Value = "B" Or rng.Value = "Z" Then
                'If true copy column F of that row into Column E
                rng.Offset(, 5).Copy rng.Offset(, 4)
            End If
        End If
    'loop
    Next rng


End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, thank you for your assistance! Can I nest this function inside another Macro? I actually need to do this three time... search for "A" "B" & "Z" and each time copy the function from column F to E.

I am also getting a run time error with the 'If rng = "A' then line'

More specifically, the error state 'Object variable or With block variable not set'

Comment: @CARoll you take what ever you want from this and add whatever is needed.  I have added the checks for B and Z to this loop.  You can add more just put an Or between.

Comment: For some reason I am getting a run-time error '13':
Type mismatch

error occurs on line:
   If rng.Value = "A" Or rng.Value = "B" Or rng.Value = "Z" Then

Comment: @CARoll You must have errors in column A such as "#N/A" or "#Value"  That is the only reason it would do that.

Comment: @CARoll i have added another if statement to deal with the cells that are errors.  See edit.

Comment: Thank you again Scott! Greatly appreciate the help :)

Comment: @CARoll please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click the green check mark by the answer.